# Add Blog Highlights to StackExchange Newsletters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, newsletter, blog-overflow

As a new blogger on DIY.StackExchange.COM, it has become apparent that the blog reader base isn't as prevalent as on maybe some of the other sites.

It would be very beneficial to some of the smaller sites (and maybe the bigger sites) to add a "This week in the blogosphere..." section to the weekly newsletter. Proposals include:

1. List of blog posts with their titles hyperlinked
2. Same as above but an excerpt is taken from the blog post.. one or two lines.

I think this would help draw attention to the sites and build a stronger user base.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

This is a good idea, so we implemented it.

Newsletters now show snippets of any blog posts created in the past 7 days. For example, the [TeX newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=tex.stackexchange.com) shows 2 posts right now:

[image: newsletter blog posts]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe most people are just interested in being here because they like Q&A sites? I always thought blogs were completely orthogonal to what Stack Exchange does, but as long as they stay separate I don't really care. The more we start nagging users about blogs (showing "NEW!" on the page when there's a new post, showing ads for them, adding a section in the newsletter), the more annoying they become for the large percentage of people that have no interest in them. There's already RSS feeds for the blogs; piggybacking on the SE newsletters because they have more readers seems like taking advantage of them

Comment: the point is not to nag and sorry if it feels that way.. but on the smaller sites the ability to promote the site and build interests exists through these extensions.